# Converting complex numbers to their x+iy form

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm quite confused as how to write the following formula into a standard form.

$$\frac{3}{4-i}$$ Rewrite into $$x + iy$$ Form I know how to do it if a number is e.g. $$\frac{1}{1+i}$$ but when the denominator isn't 1 or is positive I get confused. Could anyone explain to me step by step on how to solve the equation. I appreciate it.

Comment: Mutiply top and bottom by $4+i$.

Comment: @DavidMitra Is this the form of Ƶ(1)/Ƶ(2) where to solve it you turn it into Ƶ(1)/Ƶ(2) * ż (2)/ż (2) ? And where the ż (2) is the conjugated of Ƶ(2)?

Comment: Do you know how to rewrite $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ so that no radicals appear in the denominator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{3}{4-i}=\frac{3(4+i)}{(4-i)(4+i)}=\frac{3(4+i)}{16+1}=\frac{12}{17}+\frac{3}{17}i$$

Comment: Not going to lie you had me doubting myself there hahaha, It made sense in a way. Thanks though I got it now. much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Given $z = [(x) + i(y)] \in \Bbb{C},~: x,y \in \Bbb{R}, ~(x,y) \neq (0,0)$:

- let $\overline{z}$ denote $(x - iy)$.
- let $|z|$ denote $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$

Then, you have that $z \times \overline{z} = |z|^2.$

Therefore, $~\displaystyle \frac{1}{z} = \frac{\overline{z}}{z \times \overline{z}} = \frac{\overline{z}}{|z|^2}.$